# Start only one service on smartphone startup or application launch

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm using NativeScript, just so you know, targeting Android to begin with.

I've been trying to read up on this, but it's just impossible to understand. The Android documentation coupled with all the other answers on SO are just incomplete. *I have been at this for days.*

### Application Purpose

I want my application to do something when a new SMS is received, whether or not the user is in the application, has the application alive but not in the foreground of if the application is not even alive.

### Chronological Order

1. User turns smartphone on.
2. User downloads application.
3. User opens application for first time.
4. The application should now after opening the application should work and do something whenever a SMS has come in, regardless if the user is in the application, has it alive but not in the foreground of has killed the application or even when the smartphones screen is off and the lock is on.
5. User has forgotten to charge smartphone so smartphone dies, the user charges the smartphone and turns the smartphone on.
6. The application should immediately start to work on BOOT, doing something if a new SMS is received without having to open the application.

I have yet to find information on how to solve the above situation, in a simple example.

I don't mind the service (I presume I need) being on the main UI thread for now.

### What I Have Tried

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">

        <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

    <receiver android:name="io.basickarl.passer.ServiceStarter">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="io.basickarl.passer.SMSService" />
</application>
```

I keep seeing the following things and they are always used differently from each other, and still, it is not clear how to use them:

- Service
- IntentService
- JobIntentService
- JobScheduler
- JobService

  How do I start this service only once when starting the application for the first time like in chronological step 4, preventing this service being started several times and that it works and is listening for incoming SMS's all the time?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

> android:enabled
>
> Whether or not the broadcast receiver can be
>   instantiated by the system — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not.
>   The default value is "true". The < application > element has its own
>   enabled attribute that applies to all application components,
>   including broadcast receivers. **The < application > and < receiver >
>   attributes must both be "true" for the broadcast receiver to be
>   enabled. If either is "false", it is disabled; it cannot be
>   instantiated.**

Since in both places it is true by default the system should register the broadcast receiver by default. I don't need a service.

> android:exported
>
> messages from sources outside its application — "true" if it can, and
>   "false" if not. If "false", the only messages the broadcast receiver
>   can receive are those sent by components of the same application or
>   applications with the same user ID. **The default value depends on
>   whether the broadcast receiver contains intent filters.** The absence of
>   any filters means that it can be invoked only by Intent objects that
>   specify its exact class name. This implies that the receiver is
>   intended only for application-internal use (since others would not
>   normally know the class name). So in this case, the default value is
>   "false". On the other hand, the presence of at least one filter
>   implies that the broadcast receiver is intended to receive intents
>   broadcast by the system or other applications, so the default value is
>   "true".Whether or not the broadcast receiver can receive

I needed to set it to true on the receiver.

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:enabled="true"
    ...more code
    <receiver 
        android:name="io.basickarl.passer.HandleSMS" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Code:

```
android.content.BroadcastReceiver.extend('io.basickarl.passer.HandleSMS', {
    onReceive: async function(context, intent) {
        // ...do my stuff here
    }
});
```

Now the code runs when the application is killed or straight after a reboot.